# Angular updating array view Typescript

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

So I have an array that I need to display, problem is the array can't be populated until the page is already displayed and the user has entered a value

Stepping through my code I can see that the array is being populated correctly, however, the view isnt updated

I'm able to update it using this and an on click event

> onAddClick(){ this.CarTypes.push(newAddCar("1",true,true,1,1,"1","1"))
>   }

But when I call it through a method, it doesn't update, even though the parameters are 100% correct

> add(NMsg:string, Nom: boolean, show: boolean,image: number, order: number, id: string, name:string){
>
> this.CarTypes.push(newAddCar(NMsg,Nom,show,image,order,id,name))
>
> }

Can anyone help?

```
<div>
  <!--<ul *ngFor="let cars of CarTypes" (click)="Click(cars)">
    {{ cars.CarTypes.length ? cars.CarTypes[0].Name : '' }}
  </ul>-->

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cars of CarTypes" >
      {{cars.Name}}
    </li>
    <button (click)="onAddClick()">Add</button>
  </ul>
  <!--<select name="selectedcar" [(ngModel)]="selectedcar" ng-repeat="car as car.Name in CarTypes">{{cars}}</select>-->
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code for the view that isn't updating?

Comment: What does the markup look like?

Comment: Sorry, just editied the post

Comment: these snippets of code aren't enough to troubleshoot your issue.  A [mcve] shows all of the relevant information that is necessary to replicate the problem.  For angularjs, that means (at minimum) a complete controller definition and a full template showing the app and controller definition hierarchy, as well as the non-functional code.  Also, are you sure this is [tag:angularjs] and not [tag:angular]? it's unusual to use typescript in angularjs (1.x).

Comment: It may be unusual @Claies, but the concern here is there is AngularJS (`ng-repeat`) and Angular (`(click)`) mixed here. Marcus, please create a minimal example as previously mentioned.